# doctrine2 flush() silently crashes for no apparent reason

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, database

I'm writing a converter that takes a document from database (mongo db), does some magic with its fields and writes it back. Repeat for all relevant docs.

The problem is, after successful processing `EntityManager#flush()` just silently crashes not committing any changes to db or returning an error code.
I encountered this crash before but I've been able to evade it by reducing quantity of entities to flush(). Now it won't work even with one.

The code goes like this:

```
public function convertTagsAction() {

$result = [];
$result['docs processed'] = 0;
$result['tags added'] = 0;
$repo = $this->getRepo('Portal');
$cnt = 0;
$dm = $this->getDM();

$docs = $repo->findBy([...]);

$result['docs to process'] = count($docs);

foreach($docs as $doc) {

....//executing just for ONE doc at the moment

  $result['docs processed']++;

  //file_put_contents('1.txt', print_r($doc, true));
  //Everything is ok in the file

  $dm->persist($doc);
  echo $dm->getUnitOfWork()->size();
  // returns 6087 which I deem strange

  //this helped me before to manage this problem
  $cnt++;
  if ($cnt >= 20) {
    $dm->flush();
    $cnt = 0;
  }
}
try {
  $dm->flush();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Nah, won't tell me anything
}
return $this->success($result);
}
```

So now, whenever `flush()` is called, the script just quits and not even returns any output (should do so in the last line). Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: You never get exception or nothing usefull is there? IF you don't get exception then probably forget to add `use Exception' to your controller. Anything in dev/prod.log?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk, I forgot indeed. However, it didn't help at all. Looks like absolutely no code executes after `flush()`.

Comment: There's this entry:
`security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []`